# How to change image size according to screen resolution in codename one?

Tags: codenameone

I am new to the codename one,I am designing GUI using codename One gui and the form contains
Labels with images and couple of components and i want all images and components  are resize based on the platform please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest looking at the videos in the [How Do I? section](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i.html) specifically at the MultiImage video.

Comment: Hi Shai, When i use Calendar component it occupies more space. I want to show calendar as a pop up. I place calendar on dialog box but calendar action event is not performed.

Comment: I suggest opening a different question for that. Did you add an action listener to the calendar? We use it often in dialogs and it works.

Comment: Hi Shai, How to get Images from URL and I want apply Multi Image Concept to that images, Please Help Me.

Comment: Multi images would require you download a res file. Otherwise look at ImageDownloadService which you can find by searching here or in our discussion group: http://www.codenameone.com/discussion-forum.html